# Finding the most recent timestamp per event

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has the following columns, `|id|incident_number|created_at|note|`.

so each incident can have many updates, updates are categorized by ID, and are given a `created_at` time in the form of `2014-01-30 21:11:56`.  So one `incident_number` can have many id's and many created_at's depending on how often it is being updated.

What I am trying to do is filter out all of the other `created_at`'s by the most recent one in correspondence to time.

The catch is, is when running the query i cant look at the data and say if the created_at is less than this given date because I am unsure of when these incidents have been worked on.

big picture is I will be able to show each incident with the most recent update, *sorted* by the `created_at` date.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I ended up having to do was create a sub-query for the created_at column.  Final query looks like so...

```
SELECT Top 1
    wn.id, wn.incident_number, wn.created_at, note 
FROM
    sn_incident_work_note wn
Where
    wn.incident_number = 'INC0005607474' 

and wn.created_at = (Select MAX(iwn.created_at)
                    from sn_incident_work_note iwn
                    where iwn.incident_number = wn.incident_number)

Order By id DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a bit lost halfway through your question, but this might give you an idea:

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM ... GROUP BY incident_number
```

**EDIT:** I add this due to your comments.

Yes, MAX returns only the highest value. My statement was to help you find that value and add the others as you see fit. I guess what you need is something like:

```
SELECT MAX(created_at), incident_number, note FROM ... GROUP BY incident_number, note
```

That shows for each incident only the row with the most recent created_at timestamp.

**EDIT2:** As you mentioned an error I checked my SQL. There was the column `note` missing in the `GROUP BY` clause. I dont see the necessity for a sub-select.

Comment: That works, but it wont let me display the other columns, it only displays the MAX(created_at)

Comment: I also tried sorting by MAX(created_at), that doesnt work, gives an error.

Comment: @user2908778 Okay, I see you need further hints. I updated the answer.

Comment: haha, no that was the first thing I tried.  It returns an error.

Comment: @user2908778 I updated again. You have to add all columns you want to select to the GROUP BY clause except the one you are using aggregation (like MAX, SUM, ...) on. I forgot `note` in my example above.

Comment: I posted my solution.

Comment: @user2908778 I know, but your solution is way too complicated =)